# AVAudioPlayerNode scheduleFile:atTime:completionHandler: doesn't invoke completion handler

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, avaudioplayer, xcode7

`[AVAudioPlayerNode scheduleFile:atTime:completionHandler:]` is documented as "called after the file has completely played or the player is stopped", but is called before the file has completely played.  There does not appear to be any way to determine whether the file has finished playing, even by polling.

I have queued 10 brief sound files then logged the time and lastRenderTime for each file; it also polls the player state approximately each second.

**LOG Output**

```
2015-09-27 19:24:21.193 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 0 <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a8280: 30642.368875 s 0 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:21.194 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 1 <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a7f80: 30642.368875 s 0 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:21.601 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 2 <AVAudioTime 0x6000000a60c0: 30642.777492 s 18020 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:22.101 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 3 <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30643.276721 s 40036 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:22.270 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369853] 1 - <AVAudioTime 0x6000000a2d00: 30643.439261 s 47204 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:22.600 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 4 <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30643.775950 s 62052 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:23.099 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 5 <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30644.275179 s 84068 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:23.374 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369853] 2 - <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30644.542209 s 95844 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:23.587 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 6 <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30644.762799 s 105572 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:24.086 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 7 <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30645.262028 s 127588 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:24.180 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369853] 3 - <AVAudioTime 0x6000000a57c0: 30645.354907 s 131684 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:24.585 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 8 <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30645.761258 s 149604 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000001 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:25.085 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369939] playing 9 <AVAudioTime 0x6000000a5820: 30646.260487 s 171620 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000001 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:25.579 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369853] 4 - <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30646.748107 s 193124 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000001 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:26.547 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369853] 5 - <AVAudioTime 0x6080000a63c0: 30647.711735 s 235620 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000001 rs>
2015-09-27 19:24:27.180 AVAudioEngineCompletion[9946:369853] 6 - <AVAudioTime 0x6000000a1860: 30648.350284 s 263780 fr (/44100 Hz) 1.000000 rs>
```

I am using AVAudioPlayerNode rather than a higher-level API to play a sound file because I need to control the output device.

The task of playing audio or even audio associated with video through a selected output device was trivial with QuickTime, but there is no direct analog to set an audio device in higher-level AVFoundation APIs

Comment: The documentation says "Called after the player has scheduled the file for playback on the render thread or the player is stopped. May be nil." That means it gets called once the clip is "scheduled", not finished playing. Scheduling is almost immediate.

Comment: To get callback after playback finished, you want to call a slightly different function like this:         playerNode.scheduleFile(clip.audioFile!, at: nil, completionCallbackType: AVAudioPlayerNodeCompletionCallbackType.dataPlayedBack, completionHandler: { (completionType) in
            self.didFinish()
        })

Answer (score 1):

To get callback after playback finished, you want to call a slightly different function like this:

```
playerNode.scheduleFile(clip.audioFile!, at: nil, completionCallbackType: AVAudioPlayerNodeCompletionCallbackType.dataPlayedBack, completionHandler: { (completionType) in
    self.didFinish()
})
```